# What is the difference between screenOrientation portrait and userPortrait

Tags: android, android-orientation

I need know the real difference of `screen orientation` `userPortrait` and `portrait`. When to use what?

When this?

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

When this?

```
 android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
"portrait"  Portrait orientation (the display is taller than it is wide).
```

and

```
"userPortrait"
```

> Portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait
>   based on the device sensor and the user's sensor preference. If the
>   user has locked sensor-based rotation, this behaves the same as
>   portrait, otherwise it behaves the same as sensorPortrait. Added in
>   API level 18.

check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html